# Compare or diff two pandas columns element wise

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Pandas (but not to data science and Python). This question is not anly about how to solve this specific problem but **how to handle problems like this the panda-way**.

Please feel free to improve the title of that question. Because I am not sure what are the correct terms here.

Here is my MWE

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pandas as pd

data = {'A': [1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 4],
        'B': ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Three', 'Eins', 'Four']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
```

Resulting in

```
   A      B
0  1    One
1  2    Two
2  3  Three
3  3  Three
4  1   Eins
5  4   Four
```

My assumption is that when the value in `A` column is `1` that the value in `B` column is always `One`. And so on...

I want to proof that assumption.

Secondary I also assume that if my first assumption is incorrect that this is not an error but there are valid (human) reasons for that. e.g. see row index `4` where the `A`-value is related to `Eins` (and not `One`) in the `B` column.

Because of that I also need to see and explore the cases where my assumption is incorrect.

**Update of the question**:
This data is only an example. In real world I am not aware of the pairing of the two columns. Because of that solutions like this do not work in my case

```
df.loc[df['A'] == 1, 'B']
```

I do not know how many and which expressions are in column `A`.

I do not know how to do that with `pandas`. How would a panda professional would solve this?

My approach would be to use pure Python code with `list()`, `set()` and some iterations. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If solution should be testing if only one unique value per `A` and return all rows which failed use [`DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html) for count unique values in [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) for repeat aggregate values per groups, so possible filter rows which are not `1`, it means there are 2 or more unique values per `A`:

```
df1 = df[df.groupby('A').B.transform('nunique').ne(1)]
print (df1)
   A     B
0  1   One
4  1  Eins
```

---

```
if df1.empty:
    print ('My assumption is good')
else:
    print ('My assumption is wrong')
    print (df1)
```

Comment: I think this is it. But I played arround a bit and tried to understand. But I don't. ;) If you see a possibility to explain the solution in more atomic steps... This would be great.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter your data frame this way:

```
df.loc[df['A'] == 1, 'B']
```

This gives you the values of B where A is 1. Next you can add an equals statement:

```
df.loc[df['A'] == 1, 'B'] == 'One'
```

Which results in a boolean series (True, False in this case). If you want to check if all are true, you add:

```
all(df.loc[df['A'] == 1, 'B'] == 'One')
```

And the answer is False because of the Eins.

**EDIT**

If you want to create a new column which says if your criterion is met (always the same value for B if A) then you can do this:

```
df['C'] = df['A'].map(df.groupby('A')['B'].nunique() < 2)
```

Which results in a bool column. It creates column C by mapping the values in A in a by the list in the brackets. In between the brackets it is a groupby function of the values in A and counting the unique values in B. If that is under 2 it is unique it yields True.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, which brings to me to another point I was not aware of. I updated my question about that.

Comment: I do not understand why I have to `map()` on `df['A'].`.

Comment: The map function is used for dictionary formats. In this case, the groupby results in a Series with as index all unique values for A and as values a bool. So the map looks for each element in A if the groupby yielded True or False. I suggest saving the df.groupby('A')['B'].nunique() < 2 part as a variable and printing it or looking in the variable explorer.